# Augeo et Gaudeo

Tags: motto

> Augeo et Gaudeo

Would that be a grammatically correct way of saying: "(I) Increase and Rejoice" ?

The point of this is to make a short motto out of [Augeo](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/augeo) and [Gaudeo](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaudeo), **rather than** to say "(I) increase and rejoice", in which case I could just use the motto "Cresco et Exulto".

But, out of interest, how compatible or comparable would "Augeo et Gaudeo" be to "Cresco et Exulto"?

> [Note: "Cresco et Exulto" comes from the first line of Seneca the Younger's beautiful 34th Epistle, "On a Promising Pupil", and reads: "Cresco et exsulto et discussa senectute recalesco quotiens ex iis quae agis ac scribis intellego quantum te ipse - nam turbam olim reliqueras - superieceris." In English: "I grow in spirit and leap for joy and shake off my years and my blood runs warm again, whenever I understand, from your actions and your letters, how far you have outdone yourself; for as to the ordinary man, you left him in the rear long ago."]

And, having stated my purpose, are there other mottos I could make out of Augeo and Gaudeo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "I increase" - you increase something, or are you yourself growing larger? There is a distinction there.

While you *can* use *augeo* for the latter, it's rare and more often restricted to the former meaning. You enlarge *something*.

If you are talking about growing yourself, like "I increase in size," then you should use *cresco* or *augesco* or even *incresco*, whence "increase."

*Gaudeo* is a perfectly good word for "I rejoice."

Comment: Growing spirituality and/or in knowledge. Is Augeo only for physical growth?

Comment: @user1988 In either case, it's chiefly transitive, whereas you want an intransitive verb. Try the others I suggested, and yes, they would all work for physical growth.

Comment: so is "Augeo et Gaudeo" grammatically correct?

Comment: and Augeo can *only* refer to physical growth, but *cannot* figuratively refer to spiritual/intellectual growth?

Comment: Logeion has, for example, "periculum in dies augetur, danger is increased day by day". So could it not refer *figuratively* to, for example, knowledge growing - without actually specifying *what* is growing?

Comment: Hi @user1988. Sorry, in my comment I meant to say "Yes it would work for spiritual growth." That is fine. The problem isn't the translation, it's what you think the English words mean.

Comment: @user1988 *Augetur* is passive. That doesn't actually say "danger grows" but "danger *is increased*". Something else made the *periculum* to be increased. That's a fine distinction to make. If you must keep *augeo*, then the form would be *Augeor et Gaudeo*.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr @C.M.Weimer. Always a pleasure to hear your input ! Danke vielmals !

Comment: @user1988 Mit Vergnügen !

Comment: @Johan88 How do I get in touch with you outside SE?